# Delay on load screen objects

Tags: ios, uitableview

I don't know why but when I open the app, it takes a while to load all the data on the screen, until there remains a white screen without content. All the data loaded is downloaded from an API. What should I do to make it better?

[image: App Unloaded]

App Loaded after about 10 seconds:

[image]

I'll post below how I'm parsing all the data.
***ViewController.swift:***

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopSell: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
        @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewBanner: UICollectionView!


        var dataSource: [Content] = [Content]()
        var dataBanner: [Banner] = [Banner]()
        var dataTopSold: [Top10] = [Top10]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //SetupNavBarCustom
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.CustomNavigationBar()
            let logo = UIImage(named: "tag.png")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
            self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
            //CallAPIData
            getTopSold { (data) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dataTopSold = data
                    self.tableViewTopSell.reloadData()
                }
            }
            getBanner { (data) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dataBanner = data
                self.collectionViewBanner.reloadData()
                }
            }
            getAudiobooksAPI { (data) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dataSource = data
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        //CollectionView
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
                return  self.dataSource.count
            }else{
                return self.dataBanner.count
            }}
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

            let content = self.dataSource[indexPath.item]

            cell.bookLabel.text = content.descricao
            cell.bookImage.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")

            return cell

            }else if (collectionView == self.collectionViewBanner) {

                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCellBanner", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

                let content = self.dataBanner[indexPath.item]

                cell.bannerImage.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")


                return cell
            }
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    //TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataTopSold.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topSoldCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        let content = self.dataTopSold[indexPath.item]

        cell.labelNomeTopSell.text = content.nome
        cell.imageViewTopSell.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")

        return cell
}
}

extension UIImageView{
    func setImage(url : String, placeholder: String, callback : (() -> Void)? = nil){
        self.image = UIImage(named: "no-photo")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: url)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            guard error == nil else{
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.image = image

                if let callback = callback{
                    callback()
                }


            })

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

***DataStore.swift:***

```
import Foundation
import UIKit



    func getBanner(_ completion:@escaping ([Banner])->Void) {

        let url = URL(string: "https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/banner")

        let session = URLSession.shared

        guard let unwrappedURL = url else { print("Error unwrapping URL"); return }

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: unwrappedURL) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let unwrappedDAta = data else { print("Error unwrapping data"); return }

            do {
                let jsonBanner = try JSONDecoder().decode(BannerData.self, from: unwrappedDAta)

                completion(jsonBanner.data)

            } catch {
                print("Could not get API data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
        }


   func getTopSold(_completion:@escaping ([Top10])->Void) {

    let url = URL(string: "https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/produto/maisvendidos")

    let session = URLSession.shared

    guard let unwrappedURL = url else { print("Error url"); return}

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: unwrappedURL) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let unwrappedData = data else { print("Error data"); return}

        do {

            let jsonTop10 = try JSONDecoder().decode(Top10Data.self, from: unwrappedData)

            _completion(jsonTop10.data)



        }catch{
            print("Could no get API data")
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()

    }
```

***Model.swift:***

```
import Foundation

//Categorias
struct Contents : Decodable {
    let data : [Content]
}
struct Content : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let descricao : String
    let urlImagem : String
}
//Banner
struct BannerData : Decodable {
    let data : [Banner]
}
struct Banner : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let urlImagem : String
    let linkUrl : String
}
//Top10
struct Top10Data:Decodable {
    let data: [Top10]
}
struct Top10:Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let nome : String
    let urlImagem : String
}
```

Comment: Provide context where and how you call this APIS & load the images

Comment: Hello! I just provided details on how I'm parsing the data, could you check please?

Comment: What is the code behind every image load such as **imageViewTopSell.setImage**

Comment: It’s an extension to cast and set the UIImage easily

Comment: attach it's code

Comment: I just added in ViewController.swift

Comment: Total guess on my side; your data store has a bunch of data points/items even though you are displaying only a few on the start. Prove/disprove this by removing most items and run only with a few. If it loads fast; you need to implement some sort of data pagination.

Comment: Hello @Yohst! Well, considering your answer I thought I could make something like that: When the app launches, I will only download and display the categories and the banner, the UITableview below I’ll add an UIActivity indicator until it loads. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from it's a heavy network loading VC , you Currently don't have any problems loading the data as all are out of main thread , the only problem is loading the images as when you scroll it re-download the image again which may be just downloaded for this i recommend using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which will take care of the download & cache for you , your main problem may be low network speed for many requests

- Another thing to manage this network problem you may serial queue the download of the data that will help you load one part fastly and display it which will make the impression to the user that the app is in request for more data instead of make all the requests at once

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Do you think this ViewController is too much loaded? What would you recommend as an expert to improve it at all?

Comment: What would you do different than what I did on this project? It’s important for me to know that, because I want to improve always following the “senior” way.